# Java- Is there a method similar to hasNextInt() or hasNextDouble() for Strings? I want to check if the user input is just text and not numbers

Tags: java

I am pretty new to Java and I was stuck when I was trying to check if the user input is texts (strings) and not numbers. hasNext(), next(), nextLine() doesn't necessarily check for strings, so I am not sure how it can be done.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class CalculateOne {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.print("Enter a or b");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean isItString = scan.hasNextLine();
        while (! isItString) {
            System.out.print("Invalid Input! \n");
            scan.next();
        }
        String type = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("you chose "+type);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to use is the `hasNext(String)` or `hasNext(Pattern)` method.  These test if the next token (using the current delimiter setting) matches a regex.  There are corresponding `next` methods for consuming the token.

The details are in the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html) for `Scanner`.

So the only thing left for you to do is to "implement" the regex to match your "not a number" tokens.

---

You could also just call `next()` to get the next token and test it for "not a number".  But that is going to consume the token.

Answer (score 0):

Take your input as string and check whether input is number or a string.

```
static boolean isNumber(String s) 
        { 
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))  
                == false) 
                return false; 

            return true; 
        }
```